# jQuery data() and 'changeData' event

Tags: jquery

I can add a `click` event to an HTML element and have the `click` event update `$(document).data(key,value)`.

This would then trigger `$(document).bind('changeData', function() {...}))`. Knowing this, what would be the best way to find out which HTML element updated `$(document).data()`?

E.g.:

```
$(document).bind('changeData', function {
  // get the anchor that set $(document).data()
});

$('a').click(function() {
  $(document).data('key', 'value');
});
```

Comment: I would suggest Robert Ross's 2nd answer, but see my note underneath. Also please note, this function is not documented so should be considered experimental _AND_ maybe removed in the near future. Keep an eye [on this bug report here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7877)

Comment: noted, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Indeed, the `changeData` event is now deprecated, as indicated by @TankorSmash's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for the data by click event:

```
$('#elementSelector').click(function(e){
    $(document).data(key, val);
});

$(document).bind('changeData', function(e){
    // e.target?
});
```

If not, try storing the target within the data stored:

```
$('#elementSelector').click(function(e){
    $(document).data(key, {
        val: 'value',
        target: e.target
    });
});
```

Then when you have the change event:

```
$(document).bind('changeData', function(e){
    var data = $(this).data(key);
    var target = data.target;
    var value  = data.val;
});
```

Comment: i tried the first option but e.target returns 'document'.

However, I like the idea of your second option. That may work!

Comment: You can use `$(document).bind('changeData', function(e, key, value).....` `key` is the key that was set, `value` is the value that was set.

Comment: @Scoobler that's interesting and works...however, e still refers to `document`

Comment: I used the second approach, passing the element as an object of the key/value pair. Thanks.

Comment: Correct unfortunately in this case `e` should be treated as `this` it refers to the current object which was affected, which is document in your case. But by setting the value as an object `{val: 'value', target: ....}` you will always know what caused the data change, not just in the one instance. You could set the target with `e.target` or `$(this)` -- `$(document).data(key, {val: 'value', target: $(this)});` or `$(document).data(key, {val: 'value', target: e.target});`

Comment: Well said. And I actually did use $(this) because I have the `a` set as a jquery-ui button, which was passing a `span` as the target. therefore, as you just said, i passed it `$(this)` instead.

Comment: The difference between e.target and $(this) is that e.target can be fired from child elements that a element has an event attached too.

Answer (score 3):

https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11718

jQuery's `setData` and `changeData` events have been deprecated since 1.8 and removed in 1.9. This means that in 2.X and 3.X you're no longer able to bind to these events.

Comment: For sure, but I just spent time trying to figure out why it wasn't working. Googling "jquery changeData" doesn't mention it being removed, nor does docs for `jQuery.data()` nor the events docs. Maybe it's worth retagging the question given that it's not the same version as the rest of us.