# Does setting jQuery.data() trigger an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm wondering if calls to `$(".domElement").data("key", "newValue")` will trigger an event that I can handle? I've tried binding `change` but this doesn't get triggered when data is set.

I think this question may be asking something similar, but binding `changeData` didn't work either - [jQuery data() and 'changeData' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410314/jquery-data-and-changedata-event).

Comment: I don't think it triggers an event, if you want then you can trigger a custom event, ex `$(".domElement").data("key", "newValue").trigger('changeData')`

Comment: Ok thanks, so then how can I access the original element that triggered the event? Usually I'd just use `$(this)` in the handler but it's showing up as `undefined`.

Comment: @Matt Look at the docs for `trigger`. You won't be able to set `this`, but you can pass extra parameters that you can get in the handler

Comment: Actually forget that - `$(this)` works fine when I bind my handler to the specific selector rather than just $(document).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually you have only tried to attach the custom event but you will also have to trigger it something like:

```
$('button').click(function (e) {
    $('#someID').data("key", "newValue").trigger('changeData'); 
});

$('#someID').on('changeData', function (e) {    
    alert('My Custom Event - Change Data Called! for ' + this.id);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jr6dA/)

Answer (score 3):

It was automatic, up until [version 1.8.3](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js) (determined by searching the source for 'changeData').

However, it's written such that 'changeData' is triggered if you do:

```
$element.data('key', 'newValue');
```

but **not** if you pass an object, like:

```
$element.data({
    'key': 'newValue'
});
```

Edited source excerpts to illustrate this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    data: function( key, value ) {

        // Gets all values
        if ( key === undefined ) {
                // expurgated
            }
        // Sets multiple values
        if ( typeof key === "object" ) {
            return this.each(function() {
                jQuery.data( this, key );
            });
        }

        return jQuery.access( this, function( value ) {

            if ( value === undefined ) {
                // expurgated
            }

            parts[1] = value;
            this.each(function() {
                var self = jQuery( this );

                self.triggerHandler( "setData" + part, parts );
                jQuery.data( this, key, value );
                self.triggerHandler( "changeData" + part, parts );
            });
        },
    }
});
```

I'm not completely sure what jQuery.access does, but it looks to me (and testing confirmed) that the event only gets fired if you have passed the second 'newValue' argument.