# jQuery: Detect a change on a data element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a change on a  `data-` element to trigger element to trigger some jQuery (instead of a css class). The HTML below is generated by a Ruby Gem, so I don't have control over the id. I did add a data element.

```
<input data-number-to-text="true" class="numeric integer optional form-control" type="number" step="1" name="deck[cards_attributes][1481571763648][number]" id="deck_cards_attributes_1481571763648_number">
```

Then I am trying to target the data element, but this jQuery does not fire:

```
$(':data(number-to-text)').change(function(){
  debugger;
})
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781778/detecting-attribute-change-of-value-of-an-attribute-i-made

Comment: or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528284/does-setting-jquery-data-trigger-an-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **incorrect selector**, use `[data-number-to-text="true"]` instead of `:data(number-to-text)`:

```js
$('[data-number-to-text="true"]').change(function(){
  alert('Change triggered');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-number-to-text="true" class="numeric integer optional form-control" type="number" step="1" name="deck[cards_attributes][1481571763648][number]" id="deck_cards_attributes_1481571763648_number">
Then I am trying to target the data element, but this jQuery does not fire:
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(':data(number-to-text)')
```

is not what you want.  Try the following.

```js
$("input[data-number-to-text^='true']").change(function(){
  debugger;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-number-to-text="true" class="numeric integer optional form-control" type="number" step="1" name="deck[cards_attributes][1481571763648][number]" id="deck_cards_attributes_1481571763648_number">
```

You can get familiar with selecting element by attribute value in [MDN CSS#Attribute_selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Thanks but the long number in the ID is generated so I can't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit ... I'm trying it but it doesn't fire when I enter data in the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').on('change','input.numeric',function(){
});
```

You should always delegate
http://api.jquery.com/on/